# In jquery, I'm able to clone the image only once but not multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, clone

I'm able to  clone the image only once but not multiple times.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32pw3syh/3/)

Above  is the original fiddle which I m working on.

[Example of Cloning with drag and drops](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/1xnmtyqs/)

Above fiddle has an example of multiple drag and drops ( cloning ).

Failed JS   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32pw3syh/8/) cloned and could drag and drop only once.

My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myscore = 0;
    $(function () {
        $(".dvSource img").draggable({
            //revert: "invalid",
            axis: 'y',
                        helper: 'clone',

            refreshPositions: true,
            drag: function (event, ui) {
                ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
                var image = this.src.split("/")[this.src.split("/").length - 1];
                if ($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("draggable"), event)) {
                    switch (image) {
                        case "Desert.jpg":
                            cal = 5;
                            break;
                        case "image2":
                            cal = 10;
                            break;
                        case "image3":
                            cal = 8;
                            break;
                        case "image4":
                            cal = 10;
                            break;
                        case "image5":
                            cal = 10;
                            break;
                        default:
                            cal = 10;
                    }
                     myscore = myscore + cal;
                    document.getElementById('Score').innerHTML = myscore;
                }
                else {
                    alert(image + " not dropped.");
                }
            }
        });
        $(".dvDest").droppable({
             accept: '.dvSource div',
            drop: function (event, ui) {

                    $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());

               // ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
              //  $(".dvDest").append(ui.draggable);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Both of those JSFiddles need some serious editing before this is an approachable question.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that allows you to move multiple draggables into the droppable. Perhaps you can reverse-engineer it. http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/1xnmtyqs/